# Change back to bash from zsh? OSX Lion

Tags: bash, zsh

I am trying to setup my computer for Ruby on Rails development. All new to this.

Though I have had some problems with my Rails installation and want to reset everything and start again on setting it up.

The problem I get now is installing and using `bash` in Terminal except of the installed `zsh`.

I´m trying the command ➜  `~ rvm install 1.9.2`

but only get:

```
zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]?
```

which opens the file in an texteditor.

Isn´t it supposed to be a downloadable file, which should be installed automaticly ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like rvm is not on your path. You could specify the executable location explicitly:

```
~/.rvm/rvm install 1.9.2
```

(or maybe `/usr/local/rvm/rvm` depending on where you installed it)